# Entering values from stringstream

Tags: c++, input, stringstream

Is there a while loop that allows me to enter in all the values for a stringstream into some datatype? For example:

```
stringstream line;
while(/*there's still stuff in line*/)
{
    string thing;
    line >> thing;
    //do stuff with thing
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes:

```
std::stringstream line;
std::string thing;
while (line >> thing)
{
    // do stuff with thing
}

if (line.fail())
{
    // an error occurred; handle it as appropriate
}
```

Stream operations (like `>>`) return the stream; this is what allows you to chain stream operations, like:

```
line >> x >> y >> z
```

A stream can be used as a boolean; if the stream is in a good state (that is, if data can be read from it), it evaluates to `true`; otherwise it evaluates to `false`.  This is why we can use the stream as the condition in the loop.

There are a number of reasons a stream will not be in a good state.

One of them is when you reach the end of the stream (indicated by testing `line.eof()`); obviously, if you're trying to read all the data out of the stream, this is the condition you expect the stream to be in when you are done.

The other two reasons a stream will not be in a good state are if some internal error or if an operation on the stream failed (for example, if you try to extract an integer but the next data in the stream does not represent an integer).  Both of these are tested by `line.fail()`.

Comment: Beat me to it, I was still typing! `+1`

Comment: `for (string thing; line >> thing;) { use(thing); }`  If the condition fails in either of our loops, line.fail() will be true; you would have to break the loop for the stream to still be unfailed.  Be careful of using good (that's why I say unfailed), because !stream.fail() is not identical to stream.good().